# Replace get_context_data with get_object in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-class-based-views, generic-foreign-key

I have a CreateView in which I need to output data from an object. It works fine with this code below

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ModelName

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.project = get_object_or_404(Project, slug=kwargs['project'])
        return super(MyCreateView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context_data = super(MyCreateView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        context_data.update({'object': self.project})
        return context_data

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.project = self.project
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

but I was wondering if it's possible to replace the `dispatch()` and `get_context_data()` with a `get_object()`. I've tried the code below, but it does not give me the project as object.

```
class MyCreateView(CreateView):
    model = ModelName

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return = Project.objects.filter(slug=self.kwargs['project'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.project = self.object
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

Answer (score 2):

As their respective names imply, the `get_object` method returns a single object to be manipulated by the view, while `get_context_data` returns a dict to be displayed in the template. So no, you cannot replace one with the other, and your original code is perfectly fine.